# Impact of Browser being closed on php script

Tags: php

Suppose I have a form and I make a post to the php file. There is a duration for which the script could run. If I close the browser in the middle then will it have any effect on the script. Since script is run on the server and it has all the required parameters with it to complete its execution.

I would like to know if the script stops working at the point the browser is closed or does a script runs on the server even if the browser is closed?

Thanks in Advance

Comment: Once the request is sent to php file, it will complete its execution even if you close your browser in middle of the script execution.

Comment: it wont have any effect on the execution of the script. only the end user wont receive any response if it sends any.

Comment: http://www.php.net/manual/en/features.connection-handling.php